# Extra comma generated from an array?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I have an extra comma appearing when printing out a set at the end. The example is here:

> {1,}
>   {1, 2, 3, 4,}

This is the part printing the comma. I was reading about StringJoiner, but not sure I could this as a String.

```
if (works[i]) {
     System.out.print(" ");
     System.out.print(i+5 + ",");           
}
```

Also have tried following:

```
String str = i+5 + ",";
str = str.replaceAll(", $", "");
System.out.print(str);
```

Then it will go too:

```
{1,2 3,4}
{1}
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve. Remove the comma after the `4`? What is `i+5`?

Comment: `Arrays.stream(data).map(Objects::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(",","{","}"))`.

Answer (score 0):

After your final comma separated string is built, use the following code to replace the last comma :

```
str = str.replaceAll(",$", "");  //regex which will replace last comma
```

Let me share my test code. You can try it to see what's wrong with your code.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        String str = "1,2,3,";
        str = str.replaceAll(",$", ""); // You put space between , and $ here..
        System.out.print(str);
    }

}
```

**Output:**

> 1,2,3

Comment: See my edited post. Also please note that in your code you have a **space** between **comma(,)** and **dollar($)** : `(", $", "")`. I have removed it in my posted code : `(",$", "")`

Comment: @chatlover- Did you get a chance to look at my edited question?

Answer (score -1):

You can use streams:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
String collect =
    Arrays.stream(array).mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(i)).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
System.out.println(collect);
```

Comment: Nope. This is creates the wrong output. Also `String::valueOf` is a little more concise.